# Animate wireframe slider Blender 2.8

Tags: python, animation, wireframe

Is it possible to animate the wireframe slider in the viewport overlays using Python?[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Not with keyframes or drivers**

The overlay is a member of the 3d view space. `bpy.types.SpaceView3D`  Each property in blender has an `is_animatable` property, declaring if it can be animated.  *Visually if you right click and there is no add driver or insert keyframes*

Step thru this in the python console where `C = bpy.context`

Find which area is the 3d view

```
>>> for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     i, a.type
...     
(0, 'PROPERTIES')
(1, 'CONSOLE')
(2, 'VIEW_3D')
(3, 'TEXT_EDITOR')

>>> a = C.screen.areas[2]
```

Its 3d view space will be the active one

```
>>> s = a.spaces.active
```

And here is the overlay wireframe threshold

```
>>> s.overlay.wireframe_threshold
0.0
```

Let's see if the property def says it is animatable.

```
>>> p = s.overlay.bl_rna.properties['wireframe_threshold']
>>> p.is_animatable
False
```

Confirmed ... Nope.

There are some *dodgy* ways this could be achieved, but will wait for further details on animation required to elaborate.